# How to find currval in oracle 12c for identity columns

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I create a table in oracle 12 with a column as identity. The problem is that I want to find the current value of identity column. How I can find this, please someone help me to solve this problem...

Comment: What do you mean by finding the current value?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of the data dictionary views `*_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS`

Here is a working example.

```
create TABLE t ( ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR2(10));
Table created.

INSERT INTO t(NAME) VALUES ( 'TESTER' );  

1 row(s) inserted.

select SEQUENCE_NAME FROM user_tab_identity_cols WHERE TABLE_NAME ='T' ;

SEQUENCE_NAME
-----------
ISEQ$$_1727054
```

Now you could get the `currval` from this sequence.

```
select ISEQ$$_1727054.CURRVAL FROM DUAL;

CURRVAL
-------
1
```

[**LIVESQL DEMO**](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GJZGJEN09N7B25UQ352DDE9QA.html)  - Free OTN account required.

Comment: When i use currval without using of nextval then we can't get the current value?

Comment: @testertester : If you are using Identity columns, you don't need it. You should have run an insert at least once. But that's an entirely different question. If you found this answer useful, please mark it as answered, so that it would help others.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to know? If to insert a child row you can use the `returning` clause of the `insert` statement like this:

```
insert into master (...) values (...)
  returning master_id into l_master_id;

insert into child (master_id, ...) values (l_master_id, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

As I've written in [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/07/16/how-to-fetch-all-current-identity-values-in-oracle/), this query produces all the identities' backing sequences' `currval` values of your schema:

```sql
with
  function current_value(p_table_name varchar2) return number is
    v_current number;
  begin
    for rec in (
      select data_default
      from user_tab_cols
      where table_name = p_table_name
      and data_default is not null
      and identity_column = 'YES'
    )
    loop
      execute immediate replace(
        'select ' || rec.data_default || ' from dual', 
        '.nextval', 
        '.currval'
      ) into v_current;
      return v_current;
    end loop;

    return null;
  end;
select *
from (
  select table_name, current_value(table_name) current_value
  from user_tables
)
where current_value is not null
order by table_name;
/
```

The output could be something like this:

```
TABLE_NAME   CURRENT_VALUE
--------------------------
T1           3
T2           1
```